# What am I doing wrong to get Error: unexpected symbol when using curl in R?

Tags: r, curl, get

I am trying to download Global Fishing Watch Fishing Events data via API using R: https://globalfishingwatch.org/our-apis/documentation#events-api

When I copy the code to download a sample of the GFW data (below), I get the error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "curl --location --request GET"

and:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "-H Authorization"

I have spent hours researching and trying to correct the unexpected symbol with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

In the script below, I have already defined 'key' as the token to authorize access.

```
install.packages("curl")
install.packages("httr")

library(curl)
library(httr)

key <- gfw_auth()

curl --location --request GET 'https://gateway.api.globalfishingwatch.org/v2/events?vessels=9b3e9019d-d67f-005a-9593-b66b997559e5&datasets=public-global-fishing-events:latest&start-date=2017-01-01&end-date=2017-01-31&limit=1&offset=0' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer key"
```

I am expecting to retrieve the data described here:  https://globalfishingwatch.org/our-apis/documentation#events-api

Comment: That example `curl` command is meant to be run on your computer's command line. That's not R code. You would need to translate that into R command. There's a tool to help with that https://curlconverter.com/r/ (just make sure the command is all on one line)

Comment: If you are OK with installing packages from github, there's also https://github.com/GlobalFishingWatch/gfwr